# OnClick one of many elements with certain class and return id of element clicked (less code)

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, onclick, this

This is just an example but let's say I have this:

```
<img class"clone" id="1" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">
<img class"clone" id="2" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">
<img class"clone" id="3" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">
..... x 100

<script type="text/javascript">
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
    alert(clicked_id);
}
</script>
```

Would it be possible to make only one OnClick to the class "clone" and return me the ID of the element I clicked so that I can use it in a function?

I have about 100 images that I would generate with different IDs.

So naturally if I have to add `onClick="reply_click(this.id)` to every line it would be a lot of repetitive code.

So what I wish would be:

```
onClick -> any element with class clone -> return me the exact ID of the element clicked
```

I searched for different stuff in JS and jQuery but I think I don't know what I'm actually searching for.

Appreciate any help or recommendations what I should look up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can select all the elements with the class `clone` and adding an event listener to each of them this way:

```
const clones = document.querySelectorAll('.clone');

const divToCopyInto = document.querySelector(div);//get the div you want to copy into

clones.forEach((clone) => clone.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const newClone = clone.cloneNode(true); // or use event.target if you wish to clone the target which will probably be the image in this case
    divToCopyInto.appendChild(newClone);
}));
```

**EDIT**: after the comments, I added the desired function inside the event listener.

you should see also the [notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode#Notes) about the `cloneNode` method

Comment: here im also getting reply_click is not defined

Comment: I just used the function in your code. you should do whatever instead of using this function. the id of the element will be `event.target.id` :)

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant by just that.
Here is my real code: https://pastebin.com/uTUX93Bp
I left one with the onclick in the div to make sure to check.

Comment: i need the ID to clone the clicked img into another div

Comment: i didnt noticed that i deleted the function reply_click im very sorry

Comment: this works pretty well. However if i apply the clone class to an outer div and remove it from the img it still only copies the img.
would you mind explaing your solution to me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222832/discussion-between-saar-davidson-and-blue-lovag).

Answer (score 3):

With jQuery you can do it like this:

```
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
   alert(clicked_id);
}
    
$('img.clone').on('click', function(event) {   
    reply_click(event.target.id);
});
```

Vanilla JS (ES6):

```
const images = document.getElementsByClassName('clone');
images.forEach((img) =>
  img.addEventListener('click', (event) => reply_click(event.target.id))
);
```

Comment: so this can diffrentiate if i clicked img 1, 2 or 3 ?

Comment: Yes, event.target holds the specific element

Comment: okay why the hell didn't i just try it then or found any guy with a similar question.
Thank you very much, once i tried it out and it works im gonna come back.

Comment: im getting:
images.forEach is not a function in the vanilla JS and
 reply_click is not defined for the jqeury

Comment: You need to have the reply_click function declaration available

Comment: @BlueLovag I saw your code on pastebin, you have removed the reply_click function code, that's why it is not defined. I'll update my answer to include it

Comment: ok that was dumb on my end to be honest i didn't notice

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answers, if the `img` elements appear subsequently exactly as described in the question without other elements, you can also wrap them in a container and apply the event handler on it.

```html
<div id = "img-wrapper">
    <img class"clone" id="1">
    <img class"clone" id="2">
    <img class"clone" id="3">
    <!-- etc -->
</div>
```

Apply the event handler on the `img-wrapper`.

```js
const imgWrapper = document.getElementById('img-wrapper');
imgWrapper.addEventListener('click', (event) => reply_click(event.target.id))
```